# Collections.singleton() and forEachRemaining - Java 8

Tags: java

While working on  `Collections.singleton()` I found that it is not working as expteced. If you see the code below after `forEachRemaining`  code is neither throwing any `exception` nor returning `false` on   `itr.hasNext()`

From Java Docs of `forEachRemaining`

> Performs the given action for each remaining element until all
>   elements have been processed

The out put of below code is: **true**,**elem** and I am expecting **false**, **NoSuchElementException**

```
public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collection<String> abc = Collections.singleton("elementsItr");
        final Iterator<String> itr = abc.iterator();
        try {
            itr.forEachRemaining((e) -> {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            });
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {

        }
        System.out.println(itr.hasNext());
        System.out.println(itr.next());

    }
}
```

Please help me understand this behavior.

Comment: `forEachRemaining` doesn't seem to specify exactly in what order it calls `hasNext()`, `next()`, and your method.  The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#forEachRemaining-java.util.function.Consumer-) gives a default implementation, but that could be overridden.  You don't know what the actual `Iterator` class is, and it could override `forEachRemaining`, and it would make sense to have a special implementation for a singleton.  Basically, this is behavior you shouldn't count on.

Comment: @ajb-- I checked Java doc it is saying
The default implementation behaves as if: 
while (hasNext())
         action.accept(next());

Comment: Your esxception block is also empty, so how would you know if it is throwing an exception or not?

Comment: @ScaryWombat-- Doesn't matter if there exception or not as my pointer in iterator is at last element, so hasnext() should return false isn't it.

Comment: The **default** implementation.  It can still be overridden.

Comment: `hasNext()` means it's **not** empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the code: `Collections.singleton()` returns a `SingletonSet`.  If you call `iterator()` on a `SingletonSet`, the resulting iterator is of an anonymous class.  The anonymous class overrides `forEachRemaining`:

```
public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> action) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(action);
    if (hasNext) {
        action.accept(e);
        hasNext = false;
    }
}
```

Since your `accept` throws an exception, `hasNext` remains `true`.

Note that the javadoc doesn't specify what should happen to `forEachRemaining` if an exception is thrown; thus, it's possible that the next version of the runtime could put `hasNext = false` above the `action.accept(e)`, leading to a different result.  So you can't count on the behavior one way or the other.

Comment: Nice one! Great little find. +1

Comment: I would consider this a bug and file a ticket as such towards the OpenJDK maintainers

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire what if the tiket is already open since 2016-09-20 07:25 and the question is just a copy past of it?

Comment: @DragandDrop I would answer / edit this answer with the ticket reference to show they hit a known bug.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire, you should read [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352438/policy-on-gaming-questions) and see what is really going on.

Answer (score 2):

The iterator used by `SingletonSet<E>` that is the class used to instance the singleton when `Collections.singleton(T)` is invoked explains this behavior.
The iterator is provided by the `static <E> Iterator<E> Collections.singletonIterator(E e)` method.

This has a `hasNext` flag that pass to `false` only if the consummer has returned without exception :

```
static <E> Iterator<E> singletonIterator(final E e) {
   ...   
        @Override
        public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> action) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(action);
            if (hasNext) {
                action.accept(e);
                hasNext = false;
            }
        }
   ...
}
```

The documentation of the method doesn't explicit this behavior but we could consider it as a safe check to step forward the iterator only it was correctly consumed.
**But it gives however a hint about the exception handling :**

> Exceptions thrown by the action are relayed to the caller.

So if a exception occurs during `forEachRemaining()`, there is no guarantee on the state of the iterator as the exception is not caught by `forEachRemaining()` but forwarded to the caller.

Answer (score 2):

This had been reported in OpenJDK with [JDK-8166446](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8166446). The analysis states :

> I don't see how this would violate the specification. 
>   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#forEachRemaining-java.util.function.Consumer-
>
> """  Performs the given action for each remaining element until all
>   elements have been processed or the action throws an exception.
>   Actions are performed in the order of iteration, if that order is
>   specified. Exceptions thrown by the action are relayed to the caller. 
>   """
>
> It doesn't say whether the iterator should be "incremented" or not, if
>   accept() throws an exception.
>
> Some other classes expose the same behavior as singleton:  E.g.
>   ArrayList.Iterator has the following code: 
>           public void forEachRemaining(Consumer consumer) {  ........ 
>               } 
>               while (i != size && modCount == expectedModCount) { 
>                   consumer.accept((E) elementData[i++]); 
>               } 
>               // update once at end of iteration to reduce heap write traffic 
>               cursor = i; 
>               lastRet = i - 1;  ........  }
>
> ----------  I think it's not a bug.
>
> However, it may make sense to unify the behavior of different
>   implementations of forEachRemaining() just to make them consistent
>   with the default implementation.

With JDK 9 , this was fixed and if you test with the latest [JDK 9-ea](http://jdk9.java.net) , the output is as below:

```
Is empty: false
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.base/java.util.Collections$1.next(Collections.java:4698)
        at Test.main(Test.java:18)
```

Comment: @Pallavi--- wooow such much in-depth information regarding JDK ...you always have this much of information regarding JDK bugs and fixes...howw  are you from JDK team.....:)

Comment: Wooooowww....It feels great to directly talks to a person who drives and rectify the technology that we works on....thanks Pallavi..:) Thanks to Stack Overflow as well who created this bridge (Y)

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely you will see that you get a singleton iterator (`Collections#singletonIterator()`).

The code of it looks like that:

```
static <E> Iterator<E> singletonIterator(final E e) {
    return new Iterator<E>() {
        private boolean hasNext = true;
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return hasNext;
        }
        public E next() {
            if (hasNext) {
                hasNext = false;
                return e;
            }
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
        @Override
        public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> action) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(action);
            if (hasNext) {
                action.accept(e);
                hasNext = false;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

There you have the following lines:

```
action.accept(e);
hasNext = false;
```

As you throw a `RuntimeException` inside your lambda (called by using `accept(e)`), the variable `hasNext` is never set to `false`, because the line is not reached.